# My Bone will not stay on position

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]

My Bottem leg bone keeps doing this and i have alredy tried using edit mode how do i put it back in its proper position?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the file

Comment: I'm sorry to say that my friend, but your rig is totally messed up. This joint behaves like that because Lower_right_leg (which is wrong naming convention by the way, it should go like f.ex. Lower_leg.R) should be child of Upper_Right leg and IK constraint needs a target, not only pole target to work properly. I strongly recommend you to watch some rigging tutorials before start, and try to use RIgify addon to make your task easier)

Comment: sadly i have already tried the riggify addon but it was not working well and i figured it would be harder for to animate if i used it thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the bone needs to be connected to it's parent as shown below, this will solve your problem:

[image]